# What is the first process a typical Linux kernel starts?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I searched on the internet for which is the first process which gets executed upon system startup.

I found two answers which are `init` and `sched`. What is it really?

Which gets executed first? `sched` process or `init` process?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Typically it is the `init` process, the path of which is hard coded into the kernel itself. `init` performs very low level functions like starting `upstart` in the case of Ubuntu (prior to 15.40) or `systemd` in the case of Ubuntu 15.04 and later, Arch, Fedora, and others, which load the remaining processes and setup. Note that the system is not done booting when `init` runs - that is a common misconception. In fact, `init` sets up your login screen and other related tasks. Here's a WikiPedia page on `init`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_startup_process#SysV_init

> Init is the father of all processes. Its primary role is to create processes from a script stored in the file /etc/inittab. This file usually has entries which cause init to spawn gettys on each line that users can log in. It also controls autonomous processes required by any particular system. A run level is a software configuration of the system which allows only a selected group of processes to exist. The processes spawned by init for each of these run levels are defined in the /etc/inittab file.

However, the Linux kernel *does start* the scheduler but it is not in userspace, which is what most people associate as the home for a process. Also, the Bourne Shell (`/bin/sh`) can be substituted if the `init` is missing or cannot be called. You can also in theory substitute it for any executable by using the `init=*some path here*` Linux kernel boot option.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the reasoning. My experience is that most people think a process is whatever tools like ps and top show as a process, and that includes more than just userspace.

Comment: Well, I suppose. I still though that this reasoning is accurate - but I'd be happy to modify if you suggest a better phrasing.

Answer (score 6):

Its `sched`, as per Linux 3.13 [start kernel()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/init/main.c#L483) first calls [sched_init()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/init/main.c#L548) and runs first user space process init i.e [rest_init()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/init/main.c#L655) creates a kernel thread passing another function [kernel_init()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/init/main.c#L381) as the entry point and kernel goes to idle unless called.

```
start_kernel() {
   ...
    sched_init(); 
    rest_init(); calls function kernel_init();  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The kernel at least has one runnable process, which is known as the idle task, swapper, init_task and sched. **They are different names of the same process whose pid is 0**. This init_task is a global variable of kernel, so it have a fixed address, you can see it from System.map by command `grep 'D init_task'  /boot/System.map-*`. The address wouldn't change unless you recompile the kernel.

**The program *init* whose pid is 1, spawned by init_task(pid 0).** In Ubuntu, The program *init* is the Upstart process management daemon, while in other systems, it could be systemd. The address of init changed every time while system rebooting.

So, process 0 run first, then spawn process 1.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
pstree 0
```

it will show the all process hierarchy in tree form right from the children on `sched` process (PID 0). No doubt `init` is the parent of all process but `sched` gets executed before `init` and spaws both `init` and `kthread`.

You can also see the PPID (i.e. process id of parent process ) using:

```
ps -eaf
```

You will notice it to be 0 for both `init` and `kthread`.

Answer (score 0):

Swapper is the first process running. It has pid 0.